# python + excel: how to programmatically insert picture into comment

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I need to insert a picture into an excel cell comment box. Example of what I mean [here](http://www.computergaga.com/blog/insert-a-picture-into-a-comment/).

Is there a way to do this with an existing python library?

I have looked at both [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comments.html) and [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_comments.html#cell-comments) docs - it seems they just allow the creation of text comments.

Xlsx writer allows you to change the background color of a comment box, but it appears there is no solution for inserting a picture.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same feature yet I couldn't find it in any python library.

I ended up using Excels "Macro" feature, you can find it under the "Developer" tab
which you need to enable in File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon; it can be found on the right side amongst the Main Tabs.

After you select "Macro", give it a name and hit create it should create the sub for 
you where you can write this Visual Basic code:

```html
Sub addPic()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
    Dim pic_file As String
    Dim pic_resolution As Long
    Dim pict As Object
    
    If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then ActiveCell.AddComment
    pic_file = Application.GetOpenFilename("GIF (*.GIF), *.GIF", Title:="Select chord picture: ")
    Set pict = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    pict.loadfile pic_file
    pic_resolution = pict.VerticalResolution
    
  With ActiveCell.Comment.Shape
     .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
     .Fill.UserPicture (pic_file)
     .Height = pict.Height / pic_resolution * 96
     .Width = pict.Width / pic_resolution * 96
   End With
 
  Set pict = Nothing
   
  ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
End Sub
```

You can change the .GIF extension and resolution to whatever you need. 
Finally you should pick a keyboard shortcut which you can select
 under Macro->(Select your macro)->Options

Comment: Great idea, but this does not answer the OP's question. How then to run this macro from Python's Excel APIs? So now we have to learn how to run a VBA code from Python - code injection sort of?

Comment: I think this can be considered as an answer. There is no way to do this over python. this saved me lots o time! Thanks to the A.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can insert picture in spreadsheet using xlsxwriter. Check out [this](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html), it might help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks but my issue is not just inserting a photo into a cell.  I need to insert the picture into a comment box as shown in example.  Any idea there?

Comment: Well, I dont think that there is provision to insert image in comment using xlsxwriter.