# Add image into comment in excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I wanted to include jpeg picture available in local drive into comment in the excel through python.
How can i achieve this??

**Code for insert image in cell**

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('images.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('A2', 'image.jpg')
workbook.close()
```

**Code For write Comment**

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('comments1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('D5', 'Hello')
worksheet.write_comment('D5', "This is comment")

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Does this Help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522220/python-excel-how-to-programmatically-insert-picture-into-comment

Comment: no, this issue is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I found this in the docs

```
import xlsxwriter


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('images.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.write('A2', 'Insert an image in a cell:')
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'python.png')

# Insert an image offset in the cell.
worksheet.write('A12', 'Insert an image with an offset:')
worksheet.insert_image('B12', 'python.png', {'x_offset': 15, 'y_offset': 10})

# Insert an image with scaling.
worksheet.write('A23', 'Insert a scaled image:')
worksheet.insert_image('B23', 'python.png', {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: No sir, this code will add image in a cell, but i want to add image in comment in excel :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done... Change an excel by hand and look what changed within the excel file:

- Unzip the excel
- Rename and add the images to directory xl/media, e.g. image1.jpeg, image2.jpeg, etc.
- Add jpeg contentype to file [Content_Types].xml
- Add "relationship" file xl/drawings/_rels/vmlDrawing1.vml.rels
- Add image ids to file xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml
- If needed, change the black comment text color, the default is 'indexed="81"', in xl/comments1.xml
- Zip the excel